# Accessing Javascript Variables Within An Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

If i was to visit the source of my iframe, I notice that it has a value "srt" ,  I can access this variable by simply typing "srt" When in the iframes Source. However when it is an "iframe" typing "srt" no longer works since the variable is nested within the iframe.

How can i store the value of a variable that is in an iframe, To a variable that is not In the iframe, to access this value Outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames) collection by index or by the frame's name. Each element in the collection is the `window` object for that frame, which is where global variables are stored.

```
frames[0].srt // if there's just one
frames['frameName'].srt  // accessing by the name property
```

Or you can get the iframe element and use [contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) to retrieve the iframe's window object

```
 document.getElementById('frameId').contentWindow.srt;
```

Also remember that you can't access a frame that is not in the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the iframe has an id `frame`, from the parent:

```
var innerValue = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow['srt'];
```

Or the other way round, from within the iframe:

```
parent.iframeValue = srt;
```