# Get content window in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get a content window of an iframe.

In JQuery I have been doing this:

```
$('#loginframe')[0].contentWindow
```

However, I am unable to use JQuery in angular so trying to do this in a native way without much success:

```
  var iframe = document.getElementById('loginframe');
  var insideDoc = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the iframe need to be indexed too i.e. iframe[0]? Hard to tell without seeing the output of iframe or the page.

Comment: `document.getElementById('loginframe').contentWindow` should work. Whenever you ask a question, please explain what the problem was and any error messages. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693984/accessing-javascript-variables-within-an-iframe/19694074#19694074

Comment: Are you doing this in AngularJS (1.x) or Angular (2+)? You've tagged the question with both versions, which makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Except that in either case, you're going against the flow, hopefully for some very good reason, and it's really not an angular question at all, just vanilla JS.

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm not making any judgements about the question's contents, just the fact that it has both tags. If the OP would like to remove both because it has nothing to do with Angular or AngularJS, that would resolve the problem as well :).

Comment: @JuanMendes  I thought so too, however I get this error: unresolved variable "contentWindow"

Comment: @happycoder, you still haven't provided enough information. There is no variable called contentWindow, it's a property, so your error message is not very accurate. Is this a TypeScript compilation error? If so, you have to cast the result of document get element by id to an iframe element

Answer (score 0):

angular.element('#loginframe')[0].contentWindow

Angular uses a stripped down version of jQuery, and angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Ah, I missed that tag.